# How to find closure of $A$ in $(\mathbb R^2,d)$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Given $A=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x_1>0\}$ how do I find $Cl_{(\mathbb{R}^2,d)}(A)$?

I don't really understand how to tackle a question like this...

Comment: Is $d$ the standard metric?

Comment: yeah, the Euclidean metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this definition of closure in a metric space $(X,d)$ with $A \subset X$
$$ \bar{A} = \{ x \in X : B(x,r) \cap  \not \emptyset, \ \forall r > 0 \}$$
Intuitively we are looking for points in $X$ that interesect with $A$ for all possible neighborhoods.
Now consider the set in question. Evidently we have
$$ A = \mathbb{R}_0^+ \times \mathbb{R}$$
Naturally all points inside this region are a part of the closure (can you see why?). Next consider the points contained right outside the "edge" of our zone, so the line $(0, y)$. Can you show that these vectors also belong to the closure? What about the rest of the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: If I'm understanding this right then the closure of $A$ in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ is $\{(|x_1|,x_2): x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: Another way of reading the definition of a closure, is that we are interested in all points in $X$ that have some neighborhood with a common point in $A$. So consider $B((0,y), r)$. This is just the open ball centered at $(0,y)$. I suggest drawing a picture of the situation. If you draw a ball of any radius at that point, you will notice that it indeed does intersect with $A$. What do you know about the vectors $(\varepsilon, y), \ \forall \varepsilon > 0$? Do these belong to some ball?

Comment: they would belong to the ball $B((\varepsilon,y),r)$ and this is closed because even $r=0$ belongs to $A$?

Comment: Almost. What about $|(\varepsilon, y) - (0, y)| = \varepsilon$? It seems to me that this vector is always a part of the open ball $B((0,y),r)$ when $\varepsilon < r$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach compared to Math1000's answer is to look for points in the plane with the property that any ball drawn around them intersects the set $A$. I would suggest drawing a picture first. After drawing the picture you should see how to test this property for three different kinds of points in the plane.

Comment: This is equivalent to the sequential definition of closure.

Comment: @Math1000 yeah, it's equivalent, but it gives a different point of view to the subject. It tends to be useful, at least for me, to switch one's approach to the closure operation as situation demands :)

Answer (score 0):

The closure of a set $E$ in a metric space $X$ is 
$$\overline E = E\cup E' $$
where $E'$ is the set of limit points of $E$, i.e.\ the set of points $x$ such that $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ for some sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points in $E$. So to answer this question, you need to find the limit points of the given set.

Comment: Is every metric space a sequential space? I know that here with $(\mathbb{R}^2, \|.\|_2)$ there is no problem, but in the general case?

Comment: Ok, I would guess the limit points are $(l_1,l_2)$ where $l_1\in[0,\infty], l_2\in[-\infty,\infty]$?

Answer (score 0):

The closure of $A$ is $B := \{(x_1,x_2)\in \Bbb R^2 : x_1 \ge 0\}$. If $(x_1,x_2) \in B$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, $(x_1 + \epsilon/2,x_2) \in A$ and $d((x_1 + \epsilon/2,x_2),(x_1,x_2)) = \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$. Therefore, $(x_1,x_2)\in Cl(A)$. Conversely, suppose $(x_1,x_2)\in Cl(A)$. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $(y_1,y_2)\in A$ such that $d((y_1,y_2),(x_1,x_2)) < \epsilon$. In particular, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $y_1 > 0$ such that $|y_1 - x_1| < \epsilon$. If $x_1 < 0$, choosing $\epsilon = -x_1$, there would exist $y_1 > 0$ such that $x_1 > y_1 - \epsilon = y_1 + x_1$. This would yield $0 > y_1$, a contradiction. Therefore $x_1 \ge 0$ and hence $(x_1,x_2)\in B$. Consequently, $cl(A) = B$.